# Interact with website visitors in real-time?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to set up a page where users can perform different actions on a webpage while chatting with me.  I need to be able to have a live view of a particular DIV on the user's page that has tabs.  When I click a tab, it should update on their screen and when they click a tab, it should reflect on my screen.

Finding a chat script was easy enough, but I'm struggling to locate on Google and Stack Overflow a basic script or code snippets to acheive this.  Perhaps I'm not using the correct terms.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure but this may not be possible on web browser. Try `Team Viewer` instead

Comment: How "click tab" is different from passing text around? If you have chat working just make some message to be special to transfer clicks/selections.

Comment: Look at sites like www.trello.com. Not sure how they do it but they are doing it. :)

Comment: @DanielMarquard: What Alexei is saying is not for the user to describe what he's doing in the chat. But to use the chat as a channel to encode a custom protocol that can describe the state of the page. For example, if your browser receives the string `"<ACTION:click some_element_id>"` then in can decode it as an action by the remote user instead of a chat message and simulate the action on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is socket.io. It's really easy to use: http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to hack this into working, but, if you want a standardized way of doing it, use the Bayeux protocol. Way that this kind of communication is done by gmail, facebook and so on is via an implementation of **cometd** ([cometd.org](http://cometd.org/)). There is a lot of reference material for implementing this setup on the net.

By going this route, it's going to be a two part problem: (1) setup the environment to allow for cometd interaction

This could basically be 0 work, provided that your remote host gives you ability to run daemon scripts ex: infinite PHP scripts.

(2) write the code that will sync clients with server. This will be the low end part where you read the div, and make broadcast-level communication to all clients about it.

A good fully operational example is this [How to implement COMET with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) article.

Comment: Also, that example has an ... outdated Expires: header. Make sure it reflects this decade ;)